# do we really need a "software" tag?

Tags: discussion

In the review queue, someone provided a definition for the "software" tag.  Since the entire site is about software, what is the value of a "software" tag? And if there is value, can we think of a more suggestive term than "software" for that concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a use for it, I would say it would be for software we use to perform QA (as opposed to the QA of software). So bug-trackers, automated testing tools, etc. However, it's so generic that I don't know if it's useful. I'm going to recommend removing it. There's only 11 questions with it so it won't take long to burninate it.

The only real hiccup is the question with this as its only tag. I might just have to delete that one...